# How to grab all the elements inside a table?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML in the format of this

```
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test1 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> ... </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test2 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> .. </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test3 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> .. </tr>
 </tbody>
```

How can I iterate through all the tbody's and grab the text inside the tr/td? I tried to do the following:

```
items = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]").map(&:text)
puts items
```

and

```
items = driver.find_elements(:xpath, ".//tbody//td[1]").map(&:text)
puts items
```

In both of these cases, puts is empty (its reaching that point in code I checked). How can I grab all the items inside of the tbody/tr/td?

Comment: Have you looked at the nokogiri gem?

Comment: @MageeWorld i cant use it for my requirements

Comment: Are you looking to grab only the text in the first TD of each TR or all TDs or ?